# Expand particular navigation node onload

Tags: javascript

I have complex nested list for sidebar navigation which is used by multiple pages. What I need is the solution that expand the sidebar navigation on the particular node during onload.

I have found many similar discussions here, but the solutions provided seems not work for me. Please help;). Here is my list code:

```css
/**
 * Styling sidebar navigation
 */

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none
}


/**
 * Styling top level items 
 */

.nav a,
.nav label {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 0.4rem;
  padding-right: 0.6rem;
  padding-left: 0.6rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 #1d1d1d;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in;
  transition: all .25s ease-in;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 #1d1d1d;
}

.nav a:focus,
.nav a:hover,
.nav label:focus,
.nav label:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: #333;
}

.nav label {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 3px
}


/**
 * Styling first level lists items
 */

.group-list a,
.group-list label {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  background: #252525;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #373737;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.group-list label {
  margin-top: 2px
}

.group-list a:focus,
.group-list a:hover,
.group-list label:focus,
.group-list label:hover {
  background: #131313;
}

.group-list item {
  display: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 2px;
}


/**
 * Styling second level list items
 */

.sub-group-list a,
.sub-group-list label {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  background: #353535;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #474747;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sub-group-list a:focus,
.sub-group-list a:hover,
.sub-group-list label:focus,
.sub-group-list label:hover {
  background: #232323;
}


/**
 * Hide nested lists
 */

.group-list,
.sub-group-list,
.sub-sub-group-list {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.nav__list input[type=checkbox]:checked+label+ul {
  /* reset the height when checkbox is checked */
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav__list">
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
      <li>
        <input id="group-1" type="checkbox" hidden />
        <label for="group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Group 1</label>
        <ul class="group-list">
          <li>
            <input id="sub-group-1.1" type="checkbox" hidden />
            <label for="sub-group-1.1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Sub-group 1.1</label>
            <ul class="sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.1.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.1.3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input id="sub-group-1.2" type="checkbox" hidden />
            <label for="sub-group-1.2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Sub-group 1.2</label>
            <ul class="sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.2.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.2.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.2.3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="group-2" type="checkbox" hidden />
        <label for="group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Group 2</label>
        <ul class="group-list">
          <li>
            <input id="sub-group-2.1" type="checkbox" hidden />
            <label for="sub-group-2.1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Sub-group 2.1</label>
            <ul class="sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">sub-group item 2.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-group item 2.1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <!--End of .nav__list-->
  </nav>
  <!--End of .navigation-->
</div>
```

What I expect is to get expanded let's say "sub-group 1.1" during page onload.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu's state relies on checkboxes. If you have back-end code, you could check them before sending the HTML to the client. Otherwise, you can do this in JS:

1. Find the deepest checkbox you want to check
2. If the current element is a checkbox or if it has checkboxes as direct children, check them
3. Go up one level
4. Repeat at step 2 until you stumble onto the wrapping sidebar element

### Code

```js
// When the DOM is ready
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  openSidebar('sub-group-1.1');
});

function openSidebar(id) {
  // Can be useful if you use this function multiple times during the page's life
  closeSidebar();
  // The highest level we can go up to
  var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper'),
      // The deepest checkbox we need to check
      target = document.getElementById(id);

  // While the target is not the wrapping sidebar
  while (target !== sidebar) {
    // If the current target is a checkbox, check it
    if (target.type === 'checkbox') {
      target.checked = true;
    } else {
      // Otherwise, if it has a direct child that is a checkbox
      var checkboxChild = Array.from(target.children).find(function(el) {
        return el.matches('input[type="checkbox"]');
      });
      if (checkboxChild !== undefined) {
        checkboxChild.checked = true;
      }
    }
    // Move up one level
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
}

function closeSidebar() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#sidebar-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]');
  Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(el) {
    el.checked = false;
  });
}
```

```css
/* unchanged CSS *//**  * Styling sidebar navigation  */  ol, ul { list-style: none }  /**  * Styling top level items   */  .nav a, .nav label {     display: block;     padding-top: 0.4rem;     padding-right: 0.6rem;     padding-left: 0.6rem;     padding-bottom: 0.4rem;     color: #fff;     background-color: #333;     box-shadow: inset 0 0 #1d1d1d;     -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in;     transition: all .25s ease-in;     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 #1d1d1d; }  .nav a:focus, .nav a:hover, .nav label:focus, .nav label:hover {     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);     background: #333; }  .nav label {     cursor: pointer;      margin-top: 3px }  /**  * Styling first level lists items  */  .group-list a, .group-list label {     padding-left: 1rem;     background: #252525;     box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #373737;     font-family: Roboto;     font-size: 13px; } .group-list label {margin-top: 2px}  .group-list a:focus, .group-list a:hover, .group-list label:focus, .group-list label:hover { background: #131313; }  .group-list item {     display: inherit;     cursor: pointer;      margin-top: 2px; }  /**  * Styling second level list items  */  .sub-group-list a, .sub-group-list label {     padding-left: 1rem;     background: #353535;     box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #474747;     font-family: Roboto;     font-size: 12px; }  .sub-group-list a:focus, .sub-group-list a:hover, .sub-group-list label:focus, .sub-group-list label:hover { background: #232323; }    /**  * Hide nested lists  */  .group-list, .sub-group-list, .sub-sub-group-list {     height: 100%;     max-height: 0;     overflow: hidden;     -webkit-transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;     transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;     font-family: Roboto;     font-size: 12px; }  .nav__list input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul { /* reset the height when checkbox is checked */ max-height: 1000px; }
```

```html
<!-- unchanged HTML --><div id="sidebar-wrapper"> <nav class="nav" role="navigation"> <ul class="nav__list"> <h2>Section 1</h2> <li> <input id="group-1" type="checkbox" hidden /> <label for="group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Group 1</label> <ul class="group-list"> <li> <input id="sub-group-1.1" type="checkbox" hidden /> <label for="sub-group-1.1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Sub-group 1.1</label>             <ul class="sub-group-list">             <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.1.1</a></li>             <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.1.2</a></li>             <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.1.3</a></li>             </ul>         </li>         <li>         <input id="sub-group-1.2" type="checkbox" hidden />         <label for="sub-group-1.2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Sub-group 1.2</label>             <ul class="sub-group-list">             <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.2.1</a></li>             <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.2.2</a></li>             <li><a href="#">sub-group item 1.2.3</a></li>             </ul>         </li>         </ul>     </li>         <li>       <input id="group-2" type="checkbox" hidden />       <label for="group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Group 2</label>             <ul class="group-list">             <li>             <input id="sub-group-2.1" type="checkbox" hidden />             <label for="sub-group-2.1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>Sub-group 2.1</label>                 <ul class="sub-group-list">                 <li><a href="#">sub-group item 2.1.1</a></li>                 <li><a href="#">sub-group item 2.1.2</a></li>                 </ul>             </li>     </li>     </ul>     <!--End of .nav__list--> </nav> <!--End of .navigation--> </div>
```

Comment: My God! It works! I will mention you in my last will!